# ubuntu tar.xz multi thread compression from nautilus

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, compression

I tried to compress large file from nautilus compress menu (tar.xz). it takes huge time and i can see it use 1 thread from my cpu. I set the `XZ_DEFAULTS` environment variable to `.bashrc` but still it use a single cpu thread. how can i set nautilus to use all the 8 available cores.

in .bashrc

```
export XZ_DEFAULTS="-T 8"
```

Comment: Does it work for `tar` commands run from the terminal? I suspect the issue may be that nautilus isn't affected by `.bashrc` (since the desktop session isn't a child of an interactive shell)

Comment: @steeldriver yes compression from terminal works fine

Comment: Then I think your question is really about how to set an environment variable such that it will be available to applications in your desktop session - tbh I don't know the "right" way to do that anymore (it used to be the case that display managers typically invoked user sessions via a login shell, making `~/.profile` a good choice -  but I don't think that's true any longer)